# Bash script to go through all lines of a file one by one and count how many times a new line is different from the previous line

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am looking for a script/command to read a file with 200000 lines (each line has numbers with space between them) and when the new line is not the same as the previous line count 1 and continue like this until the end of the file.

I searched in the forum and similar questions but I couldn't find something that can help me with this.

The sample input is:

```
2 3 4 5 
3 100 105 40
2 1005 1002
2 1005 1002
4 100  105 
0 
3 100 105 40
3 100 105 40
```

The output should be:

```
5
```

Any suggestions about this?

Comment: I'm surprised by your expected output, does that mean you expect 2 of the three `3 100 105 40` lines to be removed? Even though only one of them has itself as the preceding line?

Comment: I'm with Aaron. That changes things significantly. Is the data ok to sort? If so, it sounds like a count of unique lines might be all you need.

Comment: yes, since this is a time dependence property and I need to count each time the new line differs from the previous line in a huge file. Sorry if I didn't write my post clearly. I'm new in this forum.

Comment: @Star I believe it's your expected result that is incorrect : only lines 4 and 8 are identic to the preceding line, so out of 8 total lines that's 6 lines that differ from the preceding line, not 5

Comment: The expected results is correct. You probably consider the first line as well but the first line does not have any preceding line.

Comment: Well you got your answer so I'm not sure it's worth insisting, but in both your question and a comment you mentionned the previous line, which lead me and others to think you cared about adjacent duplicates, rather than duplicates anywhere : looks like you want only 1 count of `3 100 105 40`, yet two occurences of `3 100 105 40` have a previous line that is not `3 100 105 40`. It's that second occurence that I counted to get to the count of `6` rather than `5`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're describing `uniq | wc -l`, but it would give `6` for your sample input. So maybe you want `sort -u | wc -l`.

```
$ sort -u test.txt | wc -l
5
```

#### More details

```
$ sort -u test.txt
0 
2 1005 1002
2 3 4 5 
3 100 105 40
4 100  105 

$ uniq test.txt
2 3 4 5 
3 100 105 40
2 1005 1002
4 100  105 
0 
3 100 105 40
```

(the extra blank line is part of my prompt)

Comment: Unless the data not reorderable. I have worked with order-dependant but unsorted data for which this sort of operation might be needed.

Comment: @Paul `uniq` would be the right tool in that case, eh?

Comment: `uniq` expects sorted input.  I usually use `sort -u`. When not reorderable, then yes, probably.

Comment: @PaulHodges `uniq` is usually more useful with sorted input, but its behaviour is very well defined with unsorted files. Its `man` only warns that `'uniq'  does not detect repeated lines unless they are adjacent.`

Comment: Yes. Not expressing myself well this morning.

Answer (score 3):

I would use `uniq`, removing all the duplicated consecutive lines, then `wc` to count the lines :

```
uniq input_file | wc -l
```

You can [try it here](https://ideone.com/3aTAkh) !

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I got the correct answer with sort.

Answer (score 0):

All bash implementation of the literal logic requested:

```
cnt=0
last=''
while read line
do case "$line" in
   "$last") continue ;;
   *) last="$line"
      (( cnt++ ))    ;;
   esac
done < in
echo "Total: $cnt"
```

Better implementation in `awk`:

```
$: awk 'BEGIN      { last=""; cnt=0; }
        $0 != last { last=$0; cnt++; }
        END        { print cnt;      }' in
```

Comment: Mostly just a clumsy implementation of `uniq` as an exercise, since someone had already suggested that, lol ;)